# How to make angular's services available to independent objects ; Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

In my angular app, I am trying to make a `dataAdapter` factory where I can quickly switch between the `local adapter` and the `api adapter` during development and publishing.

My dataAdapter factory looks like this

```
myApp.factory('dataAdapter', function($http, $q){
   var dataAdapter = new apiAdapter;
   //var dataAdapter = new localAdapter;
    return dataAdapter;
});
```

and my adapter objects (here api adapter) would looks something like this. (This will be located in another file called apiAdapter.js )

```
var apiAdapter = function(){
  return {
    getData : function(){ $http.get(). ....; }
  }
}
```

Now this isn't working for me, because $http is not available inside `apiAdapter` object. Now if I move `var apiAdapter = function(){....}` just before `var dataAdapter = new apiAdapter;` , it works fine. Is there a way to make the angular services available to apiAdapter without moving it inside the factory?

I hope, I have been able to describe my problem clearly.

Comment: pass `$http` as paramter to constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see a point in sharding that small functionality so in my opinion it should look like

```
myApp.factory('dataAdapter', function($http, $q){
    return {
      getData : function(){ $http.get(). ....; }
    }
});
```

but if you have to do it for some reason

```
myApp.factory('dataAdapter', function($http, $q){
   var dataAdapter = new apiAdapter($http);
   //var dataAdapter = new localAdapter;
    return dataAdapter;
});

var apiAdapter = function(http){//
  return {
    getData : function(){ http.get(). ....; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your reasons for doing this, this is how it's typically done, in the barest manner:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);

var apiAdapter = $injectorfunction(){
  return {
    getData : function(){ 
        $injector.invoke(function($http){
            $http.get();
        }); 
    }
  }
}
```

[docs reference 1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector)

[docs reference 2](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector)